# How do I add new row of data with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm creating add file function for my user, in this function, user have to insert their file name, choose their file then click on the `Add Document` button.

once user have add the document it will display back the user document under the add document button. User can add more as many as document they want.

I have trouble in adding the data. The file keep getting missing when user try to attach new file.

I want to display all file list of the user before the submitting it.

[first add document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZcgJ.png)

then user wants to add another document, the first document get replaced

[second document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWJSg.png)

how do I make it not to overwrite the older document when user add more document ?

```
<div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
     <textarea class="form-control" id="name" ></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success w-100 choseDoc">Select document</button>
   <input type="file" id="file" hidden>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info w-100" onclick="myFunction()">Add Document</button>
</div>

<div>
 <p id = "demo"></p>

</div>

 <script>
    function myFunction() {

    let filename= $('#name').val();
    let doc = $('#file').val();
                                                             
    let fileData = '';

    fileData += `<div class="tab-content col-12 mt-4" id="myTabContent-2">
                   <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="addCustodian" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="addCustodian-tab">
                      <div class="col-md-12">         
                        <ul class="perfomer-lists m-0 p-0" id="">
                          <li class="d-flex mb-4 align-items-center">
                            <img class="avatar-20 rounded ml-2" src="assets\avatar.png" style="width: 50px;">
                             <div class="media-support-info ml-3">
                                                                                                                
                              <a class="font-size-12 font-weight-600"><b>${filename}</b></a>
                                                                                                                
                              <p class="mb-0 font-size-12"> ${doc}</p>
                                                                                                            
                            </div>
                                                                                                        
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                 </div>  
               </div>
          </div> `;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fileData;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact that your approach brings some pitifals in performance you have a little logical mistake

```
<div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
     <textarea class="form-control" id="name" ></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success w-100 choseDoc">Select document</button>
   <input type="file" id="file" hidden>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info w-100" onclick="myFunction()">Add Document</button>
</div>

<div>
 <p id = "demo"></p>

</div>

 <script>
    let fileData = ''; // <--- must be declared outside your function to keep the state
    function myFunction() {

    let filename= $('#name').val();
    let doc = $('#file').val();
                                                             

    fileData += `<div class="tab-content col-12 mt-4" id="myTabContent-2">
                   <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="addCustodian" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="addCustodian-tab">
                      <div class="col-md-12">         
                        <ul class="perfomer-lists m-0 p-0" id="">
                          <li class="d-flex mb-4 align-items-center">
                            <img class="avatar-20 rounded ml-2" src="assets\avatar.png" style="width: 50px;">
                             <div class="media-support-info ml-3">
                                                                                                                
                              <a class="font-size-12 font-weight-600"><b>${filename}</b></a>
                                                                                                                
                              <p class="mb-0 font-size-12"> ${doc}</p>
                                                                                                            
                            </div>
                                                                                                        
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                 </div>  
               </div>
          </div> `;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fileData;
```